# Large scale linear programming (Data imported from .mat file)

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I tried to run a large scale linear programming with mathematica. 
I entered the code below:

```
Import["A,B.mat", "LabeledData"]
x = LinearProgramming[{0, 0, -1}, A, B, {{-1, 100}, {0, 100}, {0, 100}}];
c.x
```

where A, B are two large scale matrices. {{-1, 100}, {0, 100}, {0, 100}} are bounds of variabels of linear programming. The code doesn't work and I think there is sth wrong with importing matrices `A` and `B`. How can I fix that?

**Edit**: [Data file access from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hl06jg52jssqdl8/A,B.mat)

Comment: Please provide the data file so we can see for ourselves.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry. How can I add it to post? It is a `.mat` file (344 KB)

Comment: You will need to upload it somewhere accessible.  I'm sorry, but StackExchange does not provide that service.  Nevertheless without the data I feel that this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard data file added.

Comment: @user2667048 you can try imp = Import["A.mat", "LabeledData"]; AA = "A" /. imp ;
BB = "B" /.  imp ; x = LinearProgramming[{0, 0, -1}, AA, Flatten@BB, {{-1, 100}, {0, 100}, {0, 100}}];

Comment: @s.s.o reopened; please post an answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard done. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you carefully check what has been imported, you'll see that it imports matrix labels and the values.

```
imp = Import["A.mat", "LabeledData"];
```

> {"A" -> {{-1.13043, 1., 1.50927}, {-1.13043, 1., 1.50927},...

```
(*Get A and B matrix values*)
AA = "A" /. imp ; 
BB = "B" /. imp ;
```

And flatten BB so that it becomes a vector.

```
x = LinearProgramming[{0, 0, -1}, AA, Flatten@BB,
      {{-1, 100}, {0, 100}, {0, 100}}];
c x
```

Comment: That's work. It's amazing that definition of inequality constrained in `Mathematica` and `MATLAB` are not the same. (I can't vote up! Thanks +1)